# Understanding Python Class and Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, object

If I have this code:

```
class Fish(object):
    pass
class Salmon(Fish):
    pass
```

Is `Salmon` a object from class `Fish`? Which one is instance? What is `x = Salmon()` called?

Answer (score 2):

Let me start simple: In Python everything is an `object`.

But I guess you're confusing "object from class" (I guess you meant "instance of class" there?) with ["inheritance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)):

```
class Fish(object):
    pass
```

Creates a class `Fish` that inherits from `object`. Likewise:

```
class Salmon(Fish):
    pass
```

creates a class `Salmon` that inherits from `Fish`.

Both aren't "instances" in the normal sense. They are in fact "instances": they are both instances of `type` (which in turn subclasses object) the base metaclass for all classes but that's probably a bit too much to go into. Checkout metaclasses in Python if you want to know more.

What actually creates an `instance` is `x = Salmon()`: This creates an instance of `Salmon`.

Comment: Thx dude I get it now!!

Comment: @TeofanusGary No problem. Please don't forget to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all helpful answers and to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful one.